# Storing Object in Database column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework and planning to have a column in one of the table in my database where I can store any data (basically an object type), so I made a class and , however it didn't added DefaultValue and MaxValue columns to the database.

```
public class AssetDataType
{
    public AssetDataType()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public object DefaultValue { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public object MaxValue { get; set; }
}
```

How can I add these columns and store any values in that, I am posting code below to have an idea what I am trying to achieve.

```
protected override void Seed(AppContext context)
{
     var assetAttributeType = AddOrUpdateAssetAttributeType(context,
       new AssetAttributeType
       {
         Name = "Integer",
         DefaultValue = 0,
         MaxValue = int.MaxValue,
       });

      types.Add(assetAttributeType.Name, assetAttributeType);

     var assetAttributeType1 = AddOrUpdateAssetAttributeType(context,
        new AssetAttributeType
        {
          Name = "Boolean",
          DefaultValue = false,
        });

      types.Add(assetAttributeType1.Name, assetAttributeType1);
}
```

Comment: What is the point of defining a string length but using `object` instead of `string` as the type? If you want to store strings, use the `string` type. If you want to store integers, use int or long. Are you trying to solve some *other* problem and thought that replacing `string` with `object` may help?

Comment: I think it is [sql_variant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx).

Comment: Are you trying to create a key/value table? That is considered an anti-pattern. You also don't need it. You can use sparse columns in SQL Server to define a very large number of columns (>30000). This saves a *lot* of space if only a few of the columns are needed. You also avoid searching an entire table if you only want to retrieve a single entity's attributes

Comment: I just wanted to store a generic column where I can store any values like int,string,double etc in one column. by defining string lenth, I just wanted to male sure this column is not empty. but I guess I understand what you are trying to say , I can make it string type column and still store data as string in it. Isn't it ?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, Yes, kind of key value table only

Comment: There are a *lot* of reasons to avoid key/value tables. You can't index them so performance will suffer. They waste a lot of space because the columns have to be large enough to handle the largest value. You can't use integrity constraints. Rehydrating a single entity's values from them is an expensive operation. You can't use them as filters without resorting to expensive joins.

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos, so any idea ways how can I achieve this. Basically what i wanted is store this as data types and then create a attribute table and link this data types, for example one attribute "Name" will be of datatype string. Another attribute "Age" will be if DataType int.

Comment: @S.Akbari, so in this case a Table should be created with sql_variant datatype but it is not, EF is creating only 2 columns, Id and Name

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you want to store any objects you can serialize the objects and then store them in the database also you can retrieve the object by deserializiation.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are suggesting here with a brief example by editing this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do this. Entity-Attribute-Value / One True Lookup Table are anti-patterns in database development for a reason.

- One table containing multiple different lists overlapping is very difficult to index efficiently.
- Business logic to enforce valid entries becomes almost impossible
- Storing all the values as strings requires a lot of casting back and forth between data types. That's got a non-trivial performance cost.

Please, implement individual tables to store each individual sort of list. Allocate them the correct columns and data types, and set up basic data access classes to read them. Your code will be faster, more reliable and easier to maintain, and you'll find it won't take all that long to set up.